# Enterprise Architect set a class element to deprecated

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I just started to use EA and wondered how to indicate a class is deprecated?
Trying to have classes tagged as depreciated and appearing in a different color on existing diagramms.

Or in general say i am currently working on a POC based on an existing system and want to categorize classes for example "out of POC context", "depreciated", "undefined" etc. is it "Tagged Values" i need to go for? (because currently i just give them different colors in all the diagrams...)

**what i tryied**

Currently i am watching the tutorial videos and working with the 2888 pages manual and was able to get a hard but good start into EA but couldnt figure this out since 2 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should create a stereotype <obsolete> or <deprecated>,
- define it in some document apart, or on the note on the diagram, or both,
- and use it with classes you consider obsolete.

This algorithm does not depend on the tool.

Comment: I would recommend the status approach as suggested by Nizam rather then the stereotype approach. Stereotypes should only be used to distinguish meta-types.

Answer (score 5):

Whilst Tagged values is a good option, have you considered "Status" you can have Status configured under Settings -> Project Types -> General Types) and you can also have status colors displayed in diagrams.

Comment: actually i currently use the Status with their colours and I see this as a äquivalent solution to the stereo types. (I am however not an SW-architect and dont have much skills there so i see the above "I see this" highlighted ;) Thanks!